# OLEDB Import of CSV to VB.NET datatable reading '-' as 0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, csv, oledb

Greetings helpful delightful people,

I have a problem with reading CSV files and converting to datatables in VB.Net.
If the CSV file contains a column full of '-' then on import into the datatable they appear as '0' and the entire column is formatted in a numeric format.

The code I have written is:

```
Public Function LoadCsvFile(filePath As String) As DataTable
    Try

        DTReadCSV = New DataTable

        Dim connection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\")) & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""")

        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\") + 1) + "]", connection)
        'Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(DTReadCSV)

        'now thats its nicely in a datatable 
        IntAmountRows = DTReadCSV.Rows.Count
        IntAmountColumns = DTReadCSV.Columns.Count


        'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(DTReadCSV.Rows.Item(1)(1).ToString)
        Return DTReadCSV

        Exit Function
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())

        MsgBox(Err.Number & " " & Chr(13) & Err.Description)
    End Try
End Function
```

Please can someone smarter figure out how to combat this issue besides modifying the CSV file by taking out the '-' as blanks, which at the moment seems the only long winded way of importing these CSV files.

Many thanks

Comment: You should provide an example of this CSV file, In particular the first lines of the file

Comment: If you rework your code to work with a Schema.INI you can define that column as Text and get back "-----".  Apparently when it sees the leading '-' it assumes int and tries to get the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Schema.INI you can describe to OleDB what the CSV looks like *in detail* including resulting column names and data types.  For instance, given this data:

> "Country","Capital City","Population", "Fake"
>   "France","Paris","2.25","-----"
>   "Canada","Toronto","2.5","-----"
>   "Italy","Rome","2.8","-----"

Create a Schema.ini file in the same folder; it can have multiple sections to define various CSVs in that folder. If there is a Schema.INI in the same folder as the CSV *and* it has an entry for your CSV, OleDB will automatically use it (nothing special to do).

The Schema.INI entry for the above data may look like this:

> [Capitals.CSV]
>     ColNameHeader=True
>     CharacterSet=1252
>     Format=CSVDelimited
>     TextDelimiter="
>     Col1="Country" Text Width 254
>     Col2="Capital City" Text Width 254
>     Col3="Population" Single
>     Col4="Fake" Text Width 254

OleDb will use these definitions when reading that file, resulting in a string of dashes for the "Fake" column in the output:

[image]

One additional benefit (among many) of using a Schema.INI is that you can name the columns there rather than using or aliasing F1, F2, F3 etc.  The SQL for that output was just `"SELECT * FROM Capitals.CSV"`

Tip (for others to come): to specify UTF8 as the character set, use `CharacterSet=65001` in the schema.

For more information see
  - [Schema.ini Text File Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)
  - [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi, Many thanks however its still importing '-' as 0 even though I created the ini file

Comment: edit your post to show 2-3 lines of the CSV and also the Schema you are using.  the ---- column must be defined as text

Comment: Oops sorry had a typo error in the schema file and it works PERFECTLY thank YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sebastien Lorion's fast CSV reader.  I've been using it for almost 10 years (the source code is available and there is a Nuget package available for it if you just want to load that).

I'll include the links here to it and a code snippit that should get you what you want:

- Nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/
- Code Project Article on it:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

In this example I have the filename as an input like you do, you could also have a string, the stream, whatever you need:

```
    ''' <summary>
''' Uses Lumenworks Fast CSV reader to load a DataTable
''' </summary>
''' <param name="fileName"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function CsvToDataTable(fileName As String) As DataTable
    Dim data As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using sr As New StringReader(data)
        ' The true indicates it has header values which can be used to access fields by their name, switch to
        ' false if the CSV doesn't have them
        Using csv As New LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv.CsvReader(sr, True)
            dt.Load(csv)
        End Using

        sr.Close()
    End Using

    Return dt

End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment but I have no problem importing the csv file, just the way it imports, but thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: I understand.  I like this method because it doesn't have some of the issues that using OleDb does that require much additional setup.  Whatever works for you is good though. ;-)