# Specify datatypes in columns for data tables

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file from a persons local machine into my program here, but I'm running into a bit of a snag. One column I have is a mixture of numeric and text, such as F-23, Pool, etc. However, when I upload the file, it treats that column specifically as a decimal column. Is there anyway I can set all the column values to a string type to avoid this? I'm using Oledb right now to upload the csv into a datatable.

The code is as follows for uploading the csv into the data table.

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New 
OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & 
Path.GetDirectoryName(fullDir) & ";Extended 
Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);IMEX=1"";")
conn.Open()
Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "]", conn)
adp.Fill(dt)
conn.Close()
```

Comment: could you please show an example of the code as explained in the [mcve]

Comment: Yes - Read the file as text only

Comment: As you can see in my edit, am I not doing that in my Oledb extended properties?

Comment: Ahh yes you are. You should not need both Properties=""Text and IMEX=1 you should only need Properties=""Text. With that said I had this issue not to long ago. If the file is being updated/created in EXCEL and not Notepad or something else this will happen. My way around it was to not use Excel as the editor.

Comment: Fair enough. However, this CSV file is coming out of an application called Revu, and it just exports selected values as as CSV file. I initially tried without IMEX=1, but was reading and searching around that people found it helped, even though it doesn't.

Comment: So what I would do is when the file is exported do not open it in excel and read it directly from .NET. That should work or at least it worked for me

Comment: Hmmm... I'll take a look into that quickly here then, one second! Edit: Same deal, still treats the column that contains values such as "F-23" as numeric, due to the - in the value. Is it possible to create a schema so it just treats it as text? Like the answer listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855994/oledb-import-of-csv-to-vb-net-datatable-reading-as-0

Comment: @Phlex You could simply define a schéma for your database and then just create your own function and object and extract the data. this would only work if you know and have fixed columns that you could work with.

Comment: Yup, I know I have fixed columns to work with here, fortunately. However the file names will most likely be different every time someone wishes to use this. For a schema file, do I have to define every single column that I wish to use, or that is contained in the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way you could handle the situation if you know the column is:

Lets use small example here of personnel files.

1/ Create a **Table** with respective columns

```
CREATE TABLE My_Personnel(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  VARCHAR (1000) ,  
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Then you would create a **Class** to store the data like this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Address As String
End Class
```

Then you would create a **Function** to extract the data with the `TextFieldParser`:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

**ExtractData** Function:

```
Public Function ExtractData(ByVal csvData As String) As List(Of Person)
    Dim result As New List(Of Person)
    Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(csvData)
    Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data
    afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    ' parse the actual file
    Do While Not afile.EndOfData
        Try
            Dim tempPerson As New Person
            CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
            tempPerson.ID = CurrentRecord(0)
            tempPerson.Name = CurrentRecord(1)
            tempPerson.Age = CurrentRecord(2)
            tempPerson.Address = CurrentRecord(3)
            result.Add(tempPerson)
        Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
            Stop
        End Try
    Loop
    Return result
End Function
```

And simply **call**:

```
Dim MyPersonnel As List(Of Person) = ExtractData("C:\test.csv")
```

After this just create a function where for every Person in MyPersonnel you insert the data to your database.

**This will only work if your sure you have fixed format for your data**

Here I am using a class to store the data in case you need to modify it or work with it if you need to just insert you could just directly create an insert for every line in the extract function

Comment: Thanks for the example! But I went with quite a different approach here, since I'm not going to be operating at the database level, but simply in the datasets right now. I'll post my solution in a second here.

Comment: you can do same in dataset create your column accordingly and just load the data to it. dataset and database work similarly

Comment: This is a good answer, by the way so I'm going to mark it as correct. However, my solution is still able to keep it as a DataTable instead of a list (which would most likely be an easy change to yours anyways), but thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Phlex list of a class with a for loop can be integrated directly to a dataset. but i just think working with a class of the data makes it easy to access the values without indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is my function i use all the time for this, you can be flexible as you want by inserting if's into the for loop:-

```
Public Function convert_csv_to_data_table(ByVal File As String, ByVal separator As String)
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim firstLine As Boolean = True
    If IO.File.Exists(File) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(File)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                If firstLine Then
                    firstLine = False
                    Dim cols = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
'down here change the cols types (they are all set as string at the moment)
'however you can change by using if's, eg. if col = "field name" then dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(DECIMAL))).
                    For Each col In cols
                        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(String)))
                    Next
                Else
                    Dim data() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray)
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End If
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Seems this doesn't like the way I set things up within my application. I keep getting an error stating that `input array is longer than the number of columns vb.net`

Comment: does your csv have two headers? because its trying to identify the columns by the first line?

Comment: I suspect that your datatable does not have any columns... which if you specified a separate it should work out how many columns it needs in order to transfer the data.

Comment: Figured it out later that day actually. Turns out since this function delimits on every comma, it was breaking out values that were in quotations (such as `"32,123"`. I just simply used a text parser instead of a split and it's good to go!

Comment: Great, Glad it helped somewhat! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, as previously mentioned by Mederic and Colster, I can simply use a Schema file to change the way values are read on the specific CSV file. So in order to do this, knowing that the columns will remain constant throughout any upload, I created a schema and set the columns to their respective values.

```
Dim strSchema() As String = {"[" & ofdOpenExcelSheet.SafeFileName & "]", "ColNameHeader=True", "Format=CSVDelimited", "Col1=A Text", "Col2=B Text", "Col3=C Text", "Col4=D Text", "Col5=E Integer", "Col6=""F Space"" Decimal", "Col7=""G Space"" Decimal"}
Using outFile As New StreamWriter(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullDir) & Convert.ToString("\Schema.ini"))
    For Each line As String In strSchema
        outFile.WriteLine(line)
    Next
End Using
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Path.GetDirectoryName(fullDir) & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;MaxScanRows=0;IMEX=1"";")
conn.Open()
Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "]", conn)
adp.Fill(dt)
conn.Close()
' Remove schema since we don't need it.
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullDir) & Convert.ToString("\Schema.ini"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Would using a schema file help, that way you could define each columns type explicitly regardless of content

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading this. Since my CSV files are going to be named variously, is there a good catch-all Schema I can use, or do I have to create one programmatically on the fly? If it's the latter, do you have any examples by chance?

Comment: please check [answer] before submitting an answer and if its only a suggestion please use comments