# Opening a CSV file as a OLEDB Connection converts file text to double

Tags: vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I'm opening up a couple of CSV files and reading them in as a DataTable per the example I found [here](https://iandevlin.com/blog/2010/01/net/accessing-data-records-from-excel-and-csv-files-in-vb-net/).  The issue I am running into it the basic query I'm using to import the data is converting the column of IP addresses into Doubles.  So I want to read in 10.0.0.1 and it shows up as 10.001.  How can I get this column to read in as a string?  I would like to not double process the file if I can.

Query I'm using is basic and is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM [ComputerList.csv]
```

Here is my function to open and read the CSV file into a DataTable

```
Public Function OpenFile(ByVal strFolderPath as String, ByVal strQuery as String) as DataTable
   Dim strConn as String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFolderPath & ";Extended Propteries=""text; HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
   Dim conn as OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConn)

   Try
      conn.Open()
      Dim cmd as OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strQuery, conn)
      Dim da as OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()

      da.SelectCommand = cmd
      Dim ds as DataSet = New DataSet()
      da.Fill(ds)
      da.Dispose()

      return ds.Tables(0)
   Catch
      return Nothing
   Finally
      conn.Close()
   End Try

End Function
```

Comment: where is your code. the problem is obviously not on this line :)

Comment: You might want to look at the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: @MutedDisk I've added the code

Comment: OleDB will guess at the data type unless you help it.  You can define the column types using a [schema file as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28856448/1070452).  This will work for CSV files but not Excel

Comment: @peterG you were correct.  The TextFieldParser was the best fit for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I tried variations of everyone's suggested and have settled on a hybrid between all of them.  My goal was to read in a CSV file manipulate it in a DataTable form and them write it back out.  Some of my CSV files had multiple lines with in a cell and some had deliminators within a cell.  Below you can find my hybrid solution that utilized TextFieldParser to read in the file and break it up.

```
Public Function OpenFile(ByVal File as String, NyVal delim as String) as DataTable
   Dim dt as New DataTable()
   Dim firstline as Boolean = True
   Using MyReader as New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(File)
      MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
      MyReader.SetDelimiters(delim)
      Dim currentRow as String()

      While Not MyReader.EndOfData
         Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

            If firstline
               firstline = false
               For Each col in currentRow
                  dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col.ToString(), System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
               Next
            Else
               dt.Rows.Add(currentRow.ToArray())
            End If
         Catch ex as Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            Console.WriteLIne("Line " + ex.Message + " is not valid and will be skipped")
         End Try
      End While
   End Using

   return dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this to read csv's and force all to string.

```
Public Function convert_csv_to_data_table(ByVal File As String, ByVal separator As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim firstLine As Boolean = True
    If IO.File.Exists(File) Then
        Using sr As New StreamReader(File)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                If firstLine Then
                    firstLine = False
                    Dim cols = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    For Each col In cols
                        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(String)))
                    Next
                Else
                    Dim data() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray)
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End If
    Return dt
End Function
```

EDIT:- this will only work with a separator btw

Comment: I tried this while it worked better than most other solutions it hiccuped on CSV files that contained multiple lines within the cell and had deliminators in it as well. I did bits and pieces of this in my solution